# Click function not working inside div, but works outside

Tags: jquery

I'm having a strange problem where my jQuery code will execute just fine outside of #panel but not in it.

The code below toggles #panel. When a.close_panel is clicked, nothing happens, no console log and the div does not hide. When I a.close_panel outside #panel, it works as expected. Essentially, jQuery interactions are not working in any way when coming from inside #panel.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<body>
    <div id="panel">
        <a class="close_panel" href="#">close X</a>
    </div>

    <div class="page_wrapper">
        <a class="show_panel" href="#">Show Panel</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "a.show_panel" ).click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        // Show Panel
        $( "#panel" ).show();
        console.log( "show" );
    });

    $( "a.close_panel" ).click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $( "#panel" ).hide();
        console.log( "hide" );
    });
});
```

```
#panel {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: $gap/2;
    background-color: $white; 
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: You've not included .show class - does it disable pointer events?

Comment: You might also like to put your code in a snipper (`[<>]`) so we can see it (not) working.